# Coarse mesh of a sphere

Tags: mesh, discretization

I try to mesh a sphere (examplary) in different qualities, using `MaxCellMeasure`:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> #] & /@ {.1, 1, 10}
```

[image]

but result shows no diffenerence.

What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: You need to shrink `AccuracyGoal` as well: `DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01, AccuracyGoal -> 0]`.

Comment: @J.M. Very clever, how should one come up with this? Thanks!

Comment: @rhemans The area of the sphere `4Pi` is   greater than `.1, 1., 10 `, that's why I expected to be  smaller than default!

Comment: @rhemans It depends, here we have a Boundary mesh, that's why "Area" should be default.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann,  Compare `DiscretizeRegion[
    Sphere[]
    , AccuracyGoal->0
    , MaxCellMeasure -> {#->0.5}
] & /@ {"Volume","Area","Length"}` with `DiscretizeRegion[
    Ball[]
    , AccuracyGoal->0
    , MaxCellMeasure -> 0.5
]`.

Comment: @rhemans Astonishing because `Volume[Sphere[]]`gives `Undefined`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann probably you could extend your question to being able to predict the defaults and whole behaviour. The numbers still don't makes sense to me at least.

Comment: `Volume[Ball[]]` gives $\frac{4 \pi }{3}$. I think `Sphere` is surface only just like in 2D where `Disk[]` has area, but `Circle[]` doesn't.

Comment: What @Syed said: `Ball[]` and `Disk[]` are "full" regions, while `Sphere[]` and `Circle[]` are a dimension less than their embedding dimension.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the default figure for `MaxCellMeasure ` is `"Volume"` both for `Ball` and `Sphere`.

Comment: Evaluate if you have made it thus far: `Perimeter /@ {Circle[], Disk[]}` vs `ArcLength /@ {Circle[], Disk[]}` vs `Perimeter /@ {Sphere[], Ball[]}`. For reference: `guide/GeometricSpecialRegions`.

Comment: @Syed What are we supposed to understand from those evaluations? I think we all agree here that Sphere is the shell and Ball is the volume object, respectively. The problem here is how to understand the fact that `MaxCellMeasure` *somehow* is able to use a "Volume" specification on `Sphere`, and in fact *that's what it seems to default to*. We do not understand how the volume of those polygonal cells is even defined, particularly in light of what you and JM mentioned as well.

Comment: That our textbook notions of these terms don't readily coincide with Mathematica's implementation of these primitives and the documentation doesn't offer more help than it does. What I have gathered so far is that function defined for `nD` region will work on an `nD` primitive but perhaps (as in this case) there are exceptions.

Comment: Has anybody already asked Wolfram Support about it? I would very much like to see a good answer on what are the default figures of interest in each case, in which units and how that makes sense. I would be happy to bounty this question.

Comment: @rhermans I contacted Wolfram Support!

Comment: @rhermans - I don't understand how the deleted answer doesn't answer the question. Doesn't it show how to generate a coarsely meshed sphere?

Comment: @JasonB. It provides a way to generate coarser mesh, but it doesn't explain the behaviour. The question was **"What could be the reason?"**. After the comment by @J.M it's clear that the explanation involves the relationship between `MaxCellMeasure`  and `AccuracyGoal`, but that relationship is obscure as the default figure of interest are not what one would expect.  The answer at hand doesn't acknowledge any of that complexity and goes on a tangent that doesn't address the reasoning that explain the outcome.

Comment: I guess I think "How to generate a coarse spherical mesh?" is an answerable question, and happens to match the title of this post.  If the question is strictly confined to "What could be the reason?" then I vote to close because it requires an answer from the `DiscretizeRegion` developers.

Comment: @JasonB. I have suggested changing the scope of the question, but the title and question remain *"Coarse mesh of a sphere"* and *"What could be the reason?"*.  I think it is interesting to understand why the expected values of `MaxCellMeasure` based on Area do not work, that is the answer I am expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case `DiscretizeGraphics` does what you want:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> {2 -> #}] & /@ {.01, .1, 1, 10}
```

[image]

Funnily enough the documentation for `MaxCellMeasure` has an example similar to this question. It doesn't work now either. https://wolfram.com/xid/0dqt848dvp2-ej8ci4

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering too about this example, which doesn't evaluate as indicated. The problem with default of  `MaxCellMeasure` still persists if you change your example to `DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> { #}] & /@ {.01, .1, 1,
   10}`

Comment: I think the default dimension for `MaxCellMeasure` is `d` for a `MeshRegion` and `d-1` for a `BoundaryMeshRegion`, where `d` is the embedding dimension. Since `Sphere` has dimension 2, we need to specify it.

Comment: Probably yes, remains surprising that `DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume"-> .1}]` is accepted without error message

Comment: Also surprising the default isn’t the dimension of the region.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "SpherePoints" and "ConvexHull" like:

```
Table[ConvexHullRegion[SpherePoints[i]] // Region , {i, 50, 550, 
  100}]
```

[image]