# Coarse mesh of a tube (cylinder surface)

Tags: regions, mesh

Based on this answer [Coarse mesh of a sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269882/coarse-mesh-of-a-sphere)

```
 DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> #,AccuracyGoal -> 0] & /@ ({.001, .01, .1 } 4 Pi)
```

[image]

I would like to create a coarse mesh of a cylinder surface

```
zyl = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && -1 <= z <= 1, {x, y, z}]
 DiscretizeRegion[zyl, MaxCellMeasure -> #,AccuracyGoal -> 0] & /@ ({.001, .01, .1 } 4 Pi)
```

[image]

As you can see the meshes aren't affected by `MaxCellMeasure`!

What's wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

- For 2 dimension embeded in 3 dimension,sometimes use `MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> #}` or `MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> #}`.

```
DiscretizeRegion[zyl, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> #}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 0] & /@ ({.001, .02, .1} 4 Pi)
```

[image]

- To generate coarse surface seems not so easy. We try to decrease the `PlotPoints` and  `MaxRecursion` in `ContourPlot3D`.

```
TriangulateMesh[
 ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> 0] // 
  DiscretizeGraphics, MaxCellMeasure -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried around with the "Length" parameter but didn't get a coarse mesh ( ~10-20 triangles )